# External product feature image to external link in new tab -wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, external

I have a woocommerce store.
Its an affiliate store.
I want that when clicked on the featured image on the shop page it goes to an external website

I have added below code to my function.php its working fine just need to know **what code and where is to be added to open it in a new tab**

```
**<?php // Do not include this if already open!
/**
 * Code goes in theme functions.php.
 */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_external_products' );
function redirect_external_products() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) && ! empty( $post ) && ( $product = wc_get_product( $post ) ) && $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( $product->get_product_url() );
        exit;
    }
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to redirect in a new tab, I will suggest adding "target='_blank'" to the  tag where you display the featured image with probably the same condition as in the function above. The hacky way maybe

```
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_external_products' );
function redirect_external_products() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) && ! empty( $post ) && ( $product = wc_get_product( $post ) ) && $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        echo "<script> window.open(" . $product->get_product_url() . ", '_blank') </script>";
    }
}
```

But I strongly suggest you not to go this way!!